# Problems with the structure of my app in Go

Tags: html, go, web

So a week ago I started learning Golang by my own. I wanted to make like a Google drive web application. I learned the basics but there is one thing that I don't understand: project structure.

I searched for information about how to structure your project but I finally got confused because some people say that I have to create something like: github.com/myuser and others that I have to create 3 different folders (bin, cmd and pkg).

Could anyone give me some hints about how to structure my web project? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are practically infinite ways to structure a project, each with pros and cons. There is no right answer to this, only opinions.

Comment: Start with the [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) tutorial.

Comment: as @Adrian suggests, there are many ways to structure your project. Besides, there are some best practices that you can follow. My suggestion, go through this: https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-project-structure-best-practices/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always start small with the MVC pattern. No need to make life anymore complex than it needs to be. I usually start with a models, controllers, views, assets, router, directory and a main.go file. The structure of a project isn't important. What IS important is that YOU can understand your code and know what each section and file does.